# push value at index in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I initialize my array as myArray=[]; I want to dynamically create an associative array in a for loop. I am trying to create a key index and push a new value in at the same time. I want each key index to be a number 
like '1':  '2': '3': 
The number of indexes will be unknown so I need to create them in my loop
I am not sure how to accomplish this or push more values into each index. My code is:

```
var myArray=[];
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
myArray['1'].push(i);
myArray['2'].push(i);
myArray['3'].push(i);
}
alert(myArray);
```

There is an error in the code . I apologize if this is similar to a repeat question. I can not find this answer in my searches though. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok no I tested this and it works fine now for what I want. Thanks for pointing out I should start at index 0 too. I just wanted to push multiple values into each index. Thank you.

Comment: You could still update your question, for future visitors ...

Answer (score 3):

You must initialize the subarrays in order to `push`. Better start with the index `0`, tough.

```
var myArray = [[], [], []];
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    myArray[0].push(i);
    myArray[1].push(i);
    myArray[2].push(i);
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks. When I initialize my sub arrays do I need to surround them in curly brackets {} for objects, like the answer below?

Comment: @james Since you want to `push`, they must be subarrays, not subobjects, so use `[]`. `myArray` can either be an object or an array, you should choose depending on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript arrays should be used with numeric indexes. If you want a map from string-valued keys to values, use a simple object:

```
var myMap = {};
```

To populate the map, you'll have to initialize the arrays for each key:

```
var myMap = { '1': [], '2': [], '3': [] };
```

Then your loop will work as-is.

*edit* — I may have misinterpreted your question.  If you want your outer array to use just numeric indexes (I saw the strings and generalized, perhaps inappropriately) then you can indeed use an array of arrays:

```
var myMap = [ null, [], [], [] ];
```

(The first `null` is for index 0, which is implicitly where JavaScript array indexes start.)

Comment: C'mon, that's not the case here ... Strings can be used instead of numbers in array indices, but in OP's case the referred indicies don't contain arrays.

Comment: @Teemu ?? Huh? What's the problem?  Oh - wait do you think that he wants a 2-dimensional array? Maybe I shouldn't have taken OP at his/her word as to the string property keys (which, of course, numeric indexes are too ...) - I'll update.

Comment: ... or just omit the bracketed indicies to push a value to the newly-created array? The question is a bit ambigous though.

Comment: @Teemu it sure seems like the OP wants a 2-dimensional structure of some sort, but you're right it's not super clear.

Answer (score 0):

Several things are wrong here:

**#1**

You want `myArray` to be an associative array, so as an object, it would be defined like so:

```
myArray = {};
```

**#2**

You cannot `push()` data in an array that has not been declared. Declare those arrays first:

```
myArray['1'] = [];
myArray['2'] = [];
myArray['3'] = [];
```

**#3**

You cannot directly `alert()` an array or an object. You need to get a string representation of it:

```
alert( JSON.stringify(myArray,null,4) ); // null,4 provides easy to read formating
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo